# Spring boot applicationcontext null while updating version from 2.3.8 to 2.5.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot

my application has spring boot 2.3.8 and now I have updated to 2.5.6 but when I run the application it's shows below error in my SpringApplicationContextProvider class, while calling getBeanFactroy() method. it's seems like ApplicationContext not get autowired.

spring cloud is updated from Haxton.SRI to 2020.0.r

```
@Component
public class SpringApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    @Autowired
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * Share spring application context in application
     *
     * @return ApplicationContext object
     */
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
    {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * Returns beanFactory from ConfigurableApplicationContext
     *
     * @return BeanFactory beanFactory
     */
    public static BeanFactory getBeanFactory()
    {
        return ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) getApplicationContext()).getBeanFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Returns bean of provided class from beanFactory
     *
     * @param requiredType
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> T getBeanByClassType(Class<T> requiredType)
    {
        return getBeanFactory().getBean(requiredType);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for application context object
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

below exception has been thrown while starting application, I have added `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` line in application property.

````
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.os.SpringApplicationContextProvider.getBeanFactory(SpringApplicationContextProvider.java:42) ~[main/:na]
    at com.os.SpringApplicationContextProvider.getBeanByClassType(SpringApplicationContextProvider.java:53) ~[main/:na]
    at com.os.util.cache.ApplicationCache.getInstance(ApplicationCache.java:312) ~[main/:na]
    at com.os.listener.Startup.contextInitialized(Startup.java:170) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.os.configuration.tomcat.TomcatConfig$1.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatConfig.java:150) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.os.Main.main(Main.java:24) ~[main/:na] ```
````

Comment: Try removing the `static` from `private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;`

Comment: @pleft getBeanFactory() is static so can not remove static form this variable